# Flex Video chat/conference solution in Flex AIR

Tags: c#, wcf, apache-flex, air, video-streaming

We are developing a product where we need Video calling between 2 to 3 persons. We need solution paid or Opensource. We are using Flex/AIR on front end and C#, WCF services on the back end. Any suggestions or ideas or any links will be appreciated.
We need User Status (Online, Away, Busy etc.)
Call Alerts (user is calling accept, reject, call is rejected etc.)
Call recording and play back on request.

Platforms : Desktop, Web, Tablet's

Comment: I am currently looking at open-tok(http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/api), please suggest something like this.

Comment: Do a Google search on LiveCycle Collaboration services.  I forget its new name/home; but you may be able to build such a system on top of it.

Comment: ^http://ics.influxis.com/